# How to avoid 'join features by location' for polygon to polygon creating extra areas

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join

I am trying to work out which large polygons contain smaller ones within them in QGIS. I have a set of smaller features already defined (dark green below). However, for those smaller areas which sit on the border, using the 'join features by location' tool results in neighbouring geographies also being selected (light green). I have ensured all layers are in the same projection. Can anyone help? AM I using the right tool, or should I look at dissolve or some other tool to help?

[image: MSOA to LA join]

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do. If it's on the border, how do you determine which of the two shapes 'contains' the smaller one?

Comment: Sorry for this - basically the smaller dark green areas are geographies that are meant to be distinctly contained within the larger light green ones, according to national statistics. A spatial join works fine when they're in the centre of such a larger geography. However, when they're towards the edge, bordering another area, the 'join' function seems to pick up that second one (the bigger area in the one above). For one set of analysis I can just export the data and use a Lookup table to find the larger geography, but in a second I need to use GIS as it's not a 100% fit..

Comment: So is there light green polygon under the dark green one? If so you'd need to change the method used in your spatial join (ie, rather than intersect something like 'contains' - the specific method that works depends on the relationship). If there *isn't* any overlap, a spatial join isn't going to work because there's no relationship that can determine the correct neighbor the piece belongs to. A Dissolve based on an *attribute* would work - assuming the dark green has an attribute that says which light green it belongs to.

Comment: There is a polygon underneath; it's part of the smaller of the two light green polygons. I've just been having a look at the select features by expression tool and I can't manage to write an expression which asks 'select layer 2 feature based on if layer 1 is within it'..

Comment: Selecting by Expression is an attribute based selection. You want a spatial based expression, which is a Spatial Query (step 23 [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html)). Based on the dialog I see at step 8 [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) (which may be old), the QGIS spatial join doesn't offer a way to change the join method like [ArcGIS does](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) (see the match_option).

Comment: Thanks - this is actually really useful as I have access to ArcGIS at work, meaning I can do the analysis there. Frustrating that there isn't a way to do this in QGIS though!

Comment: I'm sure there *is* a way, I'm just not as familiar with QGIS as Arc and sometimes the tool names and such aren't the same or have different options. For instance in Arc it's Select by Location and Select by Attribute. I'm also not clear on exactly what you're trying to *do* - what does the spatial join get you? Are you trying to add attribute values of the contained areas to values of the larger ones they sit in? Just merge the shapes? Identify where they are? Identify which ones overlap, possibly note that in an attribute?

Comment: I'm trying to get to a dataset of the larger geographies which the smaller ones sit in. The small geographies are areas of risk, that sit within the larger area that Councils are responsible for. We want to know which councils are responsible.

In the end, I worked around it by using lookup tables to best fit the small areas to the larger ones, and then imported it back in. I also asked the Office for National Statistics to develop a lookup table to work out a lookup table which best fits the geography into other boundaries/responsible organisations too. Not ideal, but got the job done!

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a dataset or simply identify which large areas (Councils) have a small area (risk) they are responsible for, you have several options.

The simplest is a select by location or spatial query. You're looking for all councils that *contain* a risk. QGIS and ArcGIS tools may have different spatial relationships available to them. They may even define them differently, but [this ArcGIS help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Select_By_Location_graphic_examples/0017000000tp000000/) gives some graphic examples of available relationships. In your case you want to scroll down to the Select polygon using polygon section. These graphics can help illustrate why intersect won't work (they share a border, so they intersect), nor would completely_contains (same reason intersect doesn't work) or others. The Spatial Query screenshot at step 23 I linked to in a comment above is set to Intersect, but you'll note that's a drop-down so you can change it to a different relationship (not sure which ones exactly are available). With the right relationship you can select the desired Councils and export a list or shapefile of them.

Another method would be to Intersect the two layers. In this case intersect is an operation, not a relationship as above. What it will do is create a new set of features based on where the two inputs overlap but with the attributes of both. In your case, the result should look just like your risk layer does, but if you open the attribute table there should be a column with the Council name in it. That might even be a handy attribute to add to the risk data in the first place rather than storing it externally in a LUT or relying on having to do a spatial operation to determine the answer. This should work the same in both QGIS and ArcGIS.

There are other ways as well depending on software and license level. ArcGIS has an Identify tool (Advanced only) that can do it. And I can think of a few other workflows, but all depend on understanding spatial relationships and how they apply to the two layers.